# Limiting client application access to API from certain domains

Tags: api, security, authentication, cors

I have created an API that should only be accessed by certain client applications.
The users of these applications do not (necessarily) have to log in to use the client application. I will hand out API keys, but these will be visible on the client app, so they can also be used by other applications (?).

Is there any way to make sure the requests are coming from a specific client application, for example because they are hosted on a certain domain? I guess origin headers can easily be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

API keys are typically used to authenticate applications to a server. You are not saying what type of client you are using (native, web app, JavaScript?) You're correct that the API key may be read by another application on the client if that client has the same permissions (running in the same security context) as your client.

You could use [client certificates](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/bncbs/index.html) to have the application identify itself. But this may be a pretty heavy-handed solution depending on the security thread you're trying to mitigate. And even here an application in the same security context has access to the private key.

All other info in an HTTP request is easy to falsify.

Comment: Thanks, the client app will be JavaScript. Am I right then then that there is no real solution, as even using client certificates the private key will be visible?

Comment: Right, on most operating systems, applications run in the security context of the user. This means that the application has access to resources (files/sockets/databases) that the user is allowed to access.
So other applications, running in the same security context, they will have access to the same resources. But JavaScript apps do not have access to the key store at all as they run inside a sandbox.